# Confusion: Proof of Bertrand's Postulate, Primorial function upper bound

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

My number theory assignment walks me through the proof of Bertrand's postulate. The steps taken are essentially the same as the ones shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

I have worked out everything until the induction bit. The part I am stuck on is as follows:

[image]

I think I have proved the divisibility bit. I have gone over the proof I linked above, but I still seem to lack an understanding of the final argument made. I showed that:

$$\frac{\left(2m-1\right)\#}{m\#}\hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} \binom{2m-1}{m}$$

And I also know that:

$$\binom{2m-1}{m} \leq 2^{2m-1}$$

However, I do not know how to proceed with this argument. Any information/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have explained Bertrand's postulate [here](https://mathematicsthinking.wordpress.com/2018/03/30/bertrands-postulate-with-algorithm/), you can check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. How do you make this assertion: $$ \prod_{p\le 2n-1} p< 4^{2n-1}$$

Comment: While proving the previous lemma we need some inequality like the one you mentioned. $\prod_{p\le 2n-1}p<4^{2n-1}$ is the simplest choice.. and it's comes out to be true for $n\ge 507$..

Comment: Note that $\binom{2m-1}{m} = \binom{2m-1}{m-1}$, so it follows that $\binom{2m-1}{m} \leqslant 2^{2m-2}$. Now by the induction hypothesis you have $m\# \leqslant 2^{2m}$, so $$(2m-1)\# = m\# \cdot \frac{(2m-1)\#}{m\#} \leqslant 2^{2m}\cdot \binom{2m-1}{m} \leqslant 2^{2m}\cdot 2^{2m-2} = 2^{4m-2} = 2^{2(2m-1)}.$$